# Can a process have an owner? What does it mean?

Tags: linux, process, users

We can determine the owner of a process by using the `ps` command. Does this mean that other users cannot run / kill / resume that process?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Read [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). The [fork system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) is the way processes are created (today, `fork` is often implemented with [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) but you can see that as an implementation detail). The [exec system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)) is the way [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) programs are started. Remember that everything is done from some process with some [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)). The very first process ([init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) or [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd)) has been started magically by the kernel at boot time. Other processes have been started by [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html). Modern Linux kernels sometimes - but rarely - start magically a few special processes (e.g. `/sbin/hotplug`) or kernel threads (e.g. `kworker`, `kswapd` ....).

So yes, every [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) (and every file) has some owner (technically the [uid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier), a small non-negative number) and group (the gid). The 0 uid is for root and has extra permissions.

Read also about [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) (and [setreuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html)...) It is tricky.

> does it mean the other owner cannot run that process?

A process is *already* running (but it could be idle or waiting), so no one can run it again. Don't confuse a process (something dynamic) with the program (an executable [file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file), often in [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format) running inside it.

A given program (e.g. `/bin/bash`) can be executed in *several* processes. Many executables stay on your disk without having (at a given instant) any processes running them.

On Linux, [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) is very useful to query the kernel about the state of processes. Try for examples `cat /proc/$$/status` and `cat /proc/self/maps`. See also [pgrep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html), [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html), [top(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html).

Each process has its own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), its own [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) table, its own [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), (and often several [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)), see [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html)) etc etc...

> does it mean that other owners cannot run/kill/resume that process?

Running a process don't make any sense (it is *already* running). However, the executable of process of pid 1234 is available as the `/proc/1234/exe` symlink, and you might use that for [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) - but you probably [should not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47009791/841108) -. The permission rules for `execve` applies.

To [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) a process, you generally should have the same uid. However, the documentation tells:

> ```
>   For a process to have permission to send a signal, it must either be
>    privileged (under Linux: have the CAP_KILL capability in the user
>    namespace of the target process), or the real or effective user ID of
>    the sending process must equal the real or saved set-user-ID of the
>    target process.  In the case of SIGCONT, it suffices when the sending
>    and receiving processes belong to the same session.
> ```

To *stop* a process, use the `SIGSTOP` (or `SIGTSTP`) signal used with [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html). See [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

To *resume* a stopped process, use the `SIGCONT` signal.

Answer (score 4):

The owner is usually the user that launched that process. The command might be executable by other users, but that would be a different process.

> does it mean the other owner cannot run that process?

There is no other owner. Don't confuse programs (executable files) and processes (running programs).

> Does it mean that other owners cannot run / kill / resume that process?

The single owner already launched the process. If you mean other **users**, not owners, that depends.

Root, i.e. a user with `uid` equal to 0, has full power. Other users sharing the same `uid` are, from the OS point of view, the same user, so have full power on the process too.

Users with a different uid won't be able to kill/stop/resume the process, unless they are allowed to switch to either the owner or root privilege through `sudo` or similar command or, to a lesser extent, if they are related to that process from their hierarchy.